# PendingIntent does not let me launch an activity more than once through notifications, is there a way to solve this?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to launch an application from my apps notification. I suggest 3 applications in the notification and the user can select which one to launch.

The problem is once an app is launched through my notification, it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when the user tries to launch it for the second time from my notification.

However the app launches successfully through the launcher and gives no error. The error persists even if the device is restarted.

This is my code for launching the notification:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    try {
    foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(a,0);
    n1 = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(b,0);
    n2 = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(c,0);
    n3 = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //create intents    
       Intent notificationIntent1 = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(a);
       Intent notificationIntent2 = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(b);
       Intent notificationIntent3 = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(c);

    //create pending intents using above intents   
       PendingIntent contentIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent1, 0);
       PendingIntent contentIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent2, 0);
       PendingIntent contentIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent3, 0);


       Notification notification  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 

        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentInfo("APAU")
        .setTicker("APAU")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .addAction(0, n1, contentIntent1)
        .addAction(0, n2, contentIntent2)
        .addAction(0, n3, contentIntent3)
        .build();


       notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
       notificationManager.cancel(id-1);
```

This is the error I get in logcat when my app crashes:

```
05-09 10:15:10.953: E/AndroidRuntime(29266): java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-09 10:15:10.953: E/AndroidRuntime(29266): at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:263)
05-09 10:15:10.953: E/AndroidRuntime(29266):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:225)
```

the error ultimately points to the line:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent1, 0);
```

I solved this problem temporarily by just putting a try catch block around the pending intents. I don't expect this to be a permanent solution, but apparently it does not make that big a difference as the app still works.